# Ajax call giving me an undefined - undefined error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to update the page via Ajax so that when a user submits the form, the page is updated with the new data. Right now, it successfully inserts the data into the database, but I'm getting a "undefined - undefined" statement where I'm trying to append the new data. Any help?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="addBillForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter bill name" name="billName" class="billName">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter bill amount" name="billAmount" class="billAmount">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="addBillForm" class="addBill">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".addBill").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var billAmount = $('.billAmount').val();
    var billName = $('.billName').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: { 
            bill_amount: billAmount, 
            bill_name: billName,
            action: 'addBill'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#bills").append("<p>" + data.billName + "-" + data.billAmount + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'addBill')
{
    $billName = $_POST['bill_name'];
    $billAmount = intval($_POST['bill_amount']);
    $data = array(
        'billName' => $billName,
        'billAmount' => $billAmount,
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bills (billName, billAmount) VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $billName);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $billAmount);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#bills").append("<p>" + (data.billName - data.billAmount) + "</p>");
```

without the `( )` around your subtraction operation, Javscript will do `"<p>" + date.billName` first, resulting in a string.  And then it will do `(string) - data.billAmount` which is NaN.  Adding the `( )` forces Javascript to do the subtraction before it does the string concatenations.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized the mistake. I'm not trying to do any operations. The hyphen should have been inside quotes. I fixed that. Now I'm getting "undefined - undefined" instead of NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to subtract a number (the bill amount) from a string (the bill name)? If so, this will result in the special `NaN` value in JavaScript. If you're just trying to display the bill name, followed by a hyphen, followed by the bill amount, try this:

```
$("#bills").append("<p>" + data.billName + "-" + data.billAmount + "</p>");
```

Comment: Oops, yeah, you're right. I fixed that. But now I'm getting undefined - undefined on the page.

Comment: I think you need to add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call.

Comment: Hmm... nothing seems to get appended when I add the dataType.

Answer (score 0):

In JS the `+` is used both for concatenating strings and math operations.

So what happens when you are doing both in the same statement? Well, it starts at the left, and keeps going right.

So... `"<p>" + data.billName - data.billAmount + "</p>"`

Can be thought of as something similar to:

```
var a = "<p>" + data.billName; // string + number coerces the number to a string and concats
var b = a - data.billAmount; // ends up NaN because string minus number is no-go
var c = b + "</p>"; // NaN because any math with NaN equals NaN
```

So the result of `"<p>" + data.billName - data.billAmount + "</p>"` is `NaN`

Try putting parentheses around the math part to give it precedence.

`"<p>" + (data.billName-data.billAmount) + "</p>"`

That way the math will happen first, then the resulting numbers will be coerced to strings and concatenated with the other strings...which I'm fairly sure is what you intend.

---

**EDIT** - I see you mean you actually meant for the minus sign to really just be a string with a hyphen in it. You're now getting a string of `"undefined - undefined"` as the end result.

**Your edit completely changes the question, rendering most of the answers answering something completely different than what is now showing.** In the future with such a situation you may want to do it as a new question.

...but since we're already here...that's indicating that `billName` and `billAmount` properties on the `data` object are nonexistent/undefined.

The `data` object you use is the parameter in the `success` function of the AJAX call. You treat it like an actual object...yet in your AJAX call I don't see anywhere where you convert it to one. `data` is probably just a string of data returned from the PHP, not an object.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. How would I convert it to an object?

Comment: @shawnkauffman - From the looks of your PHP it seems to be outputting a string in JSON format. jQuery AJAX can use that as an expected format, doing it automatically if you tell it to by adding `dataType:"json"` to the object in your `$.ajax` function call. Alternatively you could just do it yourself inside your success function by using a line such as `data = JSON.parse(data);` before you use the data variable. Either way should work fine. If that doesn't work then `console.log` out your `data` string and post it so that we can be sure we're getting valid JSON format string.