# getting NaN when calculating parsed integer difference

Tags: javascript

I have a program that counts the number of lines in a text file and it works fine. What I am trying to do is count the number of lines in 2 different files and calculate their difference but I'm getting `NaN` I parsed them to integers why is it not a number? How can I calculate their difference? Thanks in advance.

```js
filePath = process.argv[2];
fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('filePath');
to_string = fileBuffer.toString();
split_lines = to_string.split("\n");
filePath2 = process.argv[2];
fileBuffer2 = fs.readFileSync('filePath2');
to_string2 = fileBuffer2.toString();
split_lines2 = to_string2.split("\n");

//logging NaN
console.log("Calc :" + parseInt(split_lines2.length) - parseInt(split_lines.length))
```

Comment: Your `.readFileSync()` calls use string constants instead of the values you get from the program arguments. Also, even if it did use the variables, both values come from the same argument.

Comment: Why are you parsing at all? The `.length` of an array will be an integer to begin with.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475941/ajax-call-giving-me-an-undefined-undefined-error/?

Comment: Don't use `+` for string concatenation. Use template literals instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a close look at this line

```js
console.log("Calc :" + parseInt(split_lines2.length) - parseInt(split_lines.length))
```

Since I don't have those var's, lets replace them with some demo numbers:

```js
console.log("Calc :" + 10 - 5);
```

This will still return `NaN` because `"Calc :10" - 5` fails.

If you enclose the sum in some brackets, there evaluated before adding to the string so it becomes `"Calc :" + 5`. Since JS will convert the `5` to a string, it producing the expected output:

```js
console.log("Calc :" + (10 - 5));
```

So you're `console.log` should look something like:

```js
console.log("Calc :" + (parseInt(split_lines2.length) - parseInt(split_lines.length)))
```

Comment: @seriously To be clear, the execution order is from left to right, so `"Calc :" + 10 - 5` will evaluate `"Calc :" + 10` first, giving the string `"Calc :10"` (string concatenation), which you then try to subtract `5` from. As you can't subtract a number from a string, you get `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Because you do math together with `"Calc :"`:

`"Calc :"` plus `split_lines2.length`, minus `split_lines.length` - no concatenation here.

Wrap calculations inside `()`, so your `+` becomes concatenation instead of addition

```js
/* filePath = process.argv[2];
fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('filePath');
to_string = fileBuffer.toString();
split_lines = to_string.split("\n");
filePath2 = process.argv[2];
fileBuffer2 = fs.readFileSync('filePath2');
to_string2 = fileBuffer2.toString();
split_lines2 = to_string2.split("\n"); */

var split_lines2 = [1, 2];
var split_lines = [1]

//logging NaN
console.log("Calc :" + (parseInt(split_lines2.length) - parseInt(split_lines.length)))
```